# xargs how to put result {} into $(cmd {})?

Tags: bash, xargs

for example:
`find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*"|xargs -I{} echo "{} =>" $(realpath {})`
I would like it to output:

```
/usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf=>/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3gf.0
/usr/lib/libblas.so=>/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3gf.0
/usr/lib/libblas.a=>/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.a
```

This will not work because the value in `$()` is expanded before the script actual running.

Is there any way I can achieve this result? without loop in bash?

Comment: This was also posted on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144226/1174) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have xargs call the shell:

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*"|xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo "{} =>" $(realpath {})'
```

Comment: this is cool, so basically it generates a small script `echo "{} =>" $(realpath {})` on the fly?

Comment: Yup. Although that small script will have had the {} already replaced by xargs with the filename.

Comment: Note that while this should work here, this is not a general solution: file names that contain shell special characters will be interpreted as shell code. In particular, if you don't have full control over the file names, this is a gaping security hole.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l \
  -exec echo -n '{} =>' \; \
  -exec realpath '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the command substitution to happen after the file name is known. So you need `xargs` to call a shell and do the substitution there.

Since you're running the command on a single file at a time, using `xargs` is a useless complication (and it also mangles some file names). Use `-exec`!

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*" -exec sh -c 'echo "$0 => $(realpath "$0")' {} \;
```

You could make this slightly faster and not less clear by not using a command substitution:

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*" -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$0 => "; realpath "$0"' {} \;
```

To make things a little faster, don't invoke a new shell process for every file:

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*" -exec sh -c 'for x; do echo -n "$x => "; realpath "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

(You can do the same with `xargs`, but just drop `xargs` and stick to the simpler, faster, more robust `-exec`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert each filename separately using line-by-line "while" loop:

```
find ... | while read f; do echo "$f" '=>' "$(realpath $f)" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest seems to be using GNU Parallel:

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*"|parallel echo {} '=\> $(readlink -f {})'
```